# JUnit5 @BeforeEach default method in interface doesn't follow "superclass first" execution order

Tags: java, junit, junit5

If `Test extends ClassA extends ClassB` , @BeforeEach will be executed in the order: ClassB, ClassA, and Test. As documented.

However `Test implements InterfaceA extends InterfaceB` doesn't have this behavior. @BeforeEach of  Test will be executed at last, but the order of InterfaceA and InterfaceB is not determined.

I expect the Interface has the same behavior as Class. And it's useful for reusing test fixtures, for example.

```
interface InterfaceB {
    @BeforeEach
    default void setup() {
        setupWebClient();
    }
}
interface InterfaceA extends InterfaceB {
    @BeforeEach
    default void setupData() {
        usingClient();
    }
}
class Test implements InterfaceA {
    @Test
    ...
}
```

Is this a bug or known limit? Any workaround?

Comment: Not sure why you would expect that behavior. An extended interface is not a superclass, or really is conceptually different.

Comment: What code in the interface are you expecting to be executed? Please provide example code.

Comment: @tgdavies Example code added. It's the same as using super classes, but with interfaces.

Comment: @daniu Thank you, you are the right point. I don't think of that, just wanted to reuse fixtures like super class, and overcome the limitation of multi heritage. Maybe I just cannot do that.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> […] just wanted to reuse fixtures like super class, and overcome the limitation of multi heritage.

The "JUnit Jupiter way" of doing this are [extensions](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions). That is, instead of dealing with inheritance, you would create separate extensions:

```java
class SetupWebClient implements BeforeEachCallback {
    @Override
    public void beforeEach(ExtensionContext context) {
        System.out.println("SetupWebClient");
    }
}

class UsingClient implements BeforeEachCallback {
    @Override
    public void beforeEach(ExtensionContext context) {
        System.out.println("UsingClient");
    }
}

@ExtendWith({SetupWebClient.class, UsingClient.class})
class MyTest {
    @Test
    void test() {
        System.out.println("Test");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
SetupWebClient
UsingClient
Test
```

Comment: Yes, thanks for replying. The extensions (as long as I understand) are not designed to depend on others. So they are not suitable to express dependence relations of fixtures, like what pytest does.

Comment: @HelloGrub ideally, tests are not dependent; yet, "there are times when it is necessary" (see [JUnit user guide 2.10.1](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-test-execution-order-methods)). The same is true for extensions, which have a well-defined [registration order](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions-registration-declarative). There are also [composed annotations](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-meta-annotations) to combine extensions in a reusable manner.